# How to control four 10-pin 7 segment display

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay

I'm a student trying to make a device for our research project so I'm quite (if not entirely) new to electronics.  I'm planning to make a 4 digit display using four 7seg display using arduino and each one of these 7 seg display has 10 pins, 8 of which i have to connect to the digital row of arduino and I cannot fit all 32 pins to the 13-pinned digital row of the arduino. I'm sure there is a way including using ICs or something, I just don't know what to do it. Sorry if I seem too knowledgeable. Thanks :)

Comment: Use shift registers.